# Optimized ListView and Adapter using the Viewholder pattern and Recycling of View

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, android-adapter

I have seen several tutorials that tell about optimizing the ListView in android using the viewholder pattern and by recycling views

Is there a third-party library available somewhere on github that has these functionalities that I can use and not write the code every time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

You can extend your List View Adapter from RecyclerView.Adapter.
This class has a better implementation for view holder pattern.

and you can implement your views faster by using Butterknife.

http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's possible for full automation building for holder.

There are some libs that help you to use View Holder via injections/annotations:

[EasyAdapter](https://github.com/ribot/easy-adapter)

[Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

But anyway, you should write some code...